# What is the proper behavior when someone abuses the close-vote superpowers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, abuse, dupehammer

I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685415/ajax-call-fails-how-to-correct-it) in the re-open vote queue.

I noticed it is marked as a duplicate of a question titled `Complete and utter nonsense`, which was a bit suspicious. So I looked at the bottom of that question and found out it was closed as duplicate by a single user with the new close-vote superpowers.

When going to the duplicate question (the one titled [Complete and utter nonsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341127/complete-and-utter-nonsense)), I noticed that the same user with the superpowers changed the title of that question and edited the only answer to say `If you're reading this, you've posted a question that makes no sense what so ever !`.

While this is quite funny, and perhaps both of the questions are low quality and don't make sense (I don't have a gold badge on the relevant tag, so who am I to say), this behavior seems to abuse both the new superpower (since if the new question makes no sense, it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of a non related question, it should be closed as off topic or unclear) and the edit privileges (what was done to the older question looks like vandalism to me).

This is definitely not a behavior I expect from a 100k+ rep user.

What do you think should be done in this case?

Comment: Flag flag flaggity flag flag

Comment: Flag the other post. Leave it to the moderators to deal with that one, that's not appropriate behaviour.

Comment: See... This is why we can't have nice things... :(

Comment: @MartijnPieters Which one to flag? The closed as duplicate question or the vandalized question and answer?

Comment: @Eran flag as "Other" for a moderator explaining the issue.

Comment: Not necessary at this point. Anna Lear is clearly aware of the issue.

Comment: In any case, I really hope this doesn't put the nail in the coffin for the gold badge dupe-votes. It's a really nice feature for everyone else who do not abuse it.

Comment: In this specific case, I've left a comment for Adeneo and the question was reopened, so I'm not sure anything else is necessary just yet. We'll be keeping an eye on how this feature is used and adjust as needed.

Comment: @Eran: either one, include a link to the other.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: When I first started reading this question, I was worried it was about me and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796322/issue-with-nested-if-statements-in-javascript. But in that case, it was the OP who edited the original question into nonsense, and I reverted it when I marked the new question as a duplicate. Note that both questions are now deleted, so you may not be able to see them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention, misusing this powerful ability is rather damaging and the moderators will put a stop to it.

I'll add that the moderators have no way to only remove this specific ability, a user that continues to misuse this privilege after being warned is likely to get their account suspended.

Comment: Here's hoping! Let the hammer strike both ways, or something...

Answer (score 49):

This is an extreme abuse of two different systems: closing and editing. Folks who engage in such behavior risk having their accounts suspended or worse.

Thank you for reporting this; the user involved has been warned.