# Let's give very-trusted users a Closehammer to go with their Dupehammer

Tags: feature-request, privileges, on-hold

<sup>I'm calling it a Closehammer rather than an Onholdhammer because... well, just look at how odd *Onholdhammer* looks.</sup>

**I'm proposing that trusted users be given the ability to instantly place a question On Hold unilaterally.**

---

Now I'd like you to read the following and reconsider undoing your downvote...

A trusted user would be defined strictly, the emphasis of this trust being based not solely on the user's reputation but on their moderation activity.  The following attributes could be used in this measure of trustworthiness:

- A good track history of successful close and delete votes
- A good track history of moderator flags

  - The user actively uses flags
  - A high percentage of these flags are marked helpful
- User has a history of being active on the website
- User has a history of being active *on the website's meta*

*In addition*, I would suggest that in order to use this power, the trusted user would have to add a comment *(wait, let me explain before you go recast that downvote!)* to explain why this extraordinary action was taken.  This also will allow the user to **cast a non-binding close vote**--If you don't leave a reason, it is a regular vote. If you do, instaclose.

I can already hear the choruses of *"asdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdf"* coming... But understand that these users are the least likely to pull this kind of BS move. And if you do, that's great!  Because we can ban you from using the closehammer, as obviously you don't care about what you're doing.

**Rationale for this proposal:**

Let's not waste lots of time and effort closing stuff that is obviously unsalvageable.

**Why this is not a duplicate:**

Note the proposed duplicate is already [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). This proposal also doesn't consider reputation as an indication of trust, is about instant closure not increased weight... it's not a match at all.

---

After some consideration, I think it should be named the **Haltenhammer**.

[image: Halt! Hammerzeit.]

Comment: *OnHoldHammer* looks less odd in PascalCase

Comment: @psubsee2003 clearly `on_hold_hammer` is the right answer.

Comment: +1 for idea, +1 for justification, -1 for my negative bias in the idea :D

Comment: Please don't require 10k for it kthxbye

Comment: +1 because "not solely on the user's reputation". Why not if they're deemed to be making good decisions. Things can always be amended or rolled back if they make the odd bad decision etc. And their rights revoked if too many bad decisions

Comment: Why do you believe there is a need for this? No rationale has been given in this proposal for why this change would be necessary and what problem it would solve. If you are unhappy with the speed at which a question you wanted closed was closed, and believe it *urgently* needs to be closed, you could raise a mod flag on it.

Comment: Besides, don't we already do this every year or so in an election?

Comment: Seeing as there are a lot of things that escape unnoticed on some sites with very high volume (Stack Overflow, for instance), I would be concerned with abuse not being discovered immediately.  And if someone does begin to abuse it, it could take a while to be seen and to be cleaned up

Comment: @psubsee2003 Handle this the same way we handle kicks in chat - raise an autoflag if one person uses it more than *x* times in *y* minutes, and only count unilateral closings for it.

Comment: @Undo It only took 51 minutes for the proposed trust metric to become distrusted and mitigation strategies to be proposed; that may not be a good sign.

Comment: @Undo but someone "abusing it" may not opt for speed.  They might just have a misguided opinion of what makes a good question.

Comment: Don't get me wrong on this, I don't hate the idea.  I see a lot of crap get answered quickly by low rep users just throwing out "how about this" ideas that could benefit from quicker closing.  But would this cause more problems than it solves?  I'm not sure on that yet.

Comment: [Yeah, what if @bjb568 gets it?](https://petersenvoicestudio.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/horror_movie_scream.jpg)

Comment: I'm thinking less of targeting this for speed, more for counting unilateral closings (no previous votes) over *x* minutes (where *x* is a very big number).

Comment: @Undo Things per time is speed regardless of the magnitude of the time.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders (and the origins of the dupe hammer as well as addressing other types of closes). Maybe a dupe, sort of?

Comment: Related to mitigation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231697/what-is-the-proper-behavior-when-someone-abuses-the-close-vote-superpowers?rq=1

Comment: @JasonC Not necessarily - in this case, we'd more be using the time as a filter so that mods only need to look at people that are doing enough damage to care. No use wasting a moderator's time on someone who is closing a question a month, even wrongly.

Comment: @JasonC The justification is obvious on its face. Not only for the utter crap, off topic, unsalvageable questions that pour in on a regular basis, but also for the hundreds of thousands that have made it past the front page and wait, festering, for years to be closed.  Why waste time with these? Shut them down immediately and move on. Saving everybody's time is never a bad thing.

Comment: @Won't It sounds like you're identifying the fundamental problem as a watering down of information quality on the site due to these questions sticking around. This isn't the best solution to that problem. At the moment, if old crap questions aren't really getting a lot of views, they don't *really* matter. Perhaps auto mod flags when old low scored questions exceed a certain view count per time would be a better way to cut down on poor information that is making its way to the general public. A crap question that nobody looks at isn't really an urgent issue, since it has very little impact.

Comment: Why do you think mods should be dealing with these questions @Jason?

Comment: @bjb568 Whether they *should* or *shouldn't* isn't something I'm really discussing. They *can*. If you'd like to start a new meta topic discussing whether or not said old questions matter and, if so, who should handle them, you may do so. Such a discussion may be useful anyways, to provide evidence and rationale for this proposal.

Comment: @JasonC I get it, you don't think it's worth the bother.  I can understand that viewpoint.  I take the other view--let's get rid of crap as fast as possible with the least amount of effort.

Comment: Of course mods *can*. They can do practically anything on the system by design. The problem here is with the delegation of responsibility of both dealing with the constant flow of crap questions and the cleanup of the huge backlog of old and abandoned questions. Both of these are handled mostly by 3kers, not mods, because mods are limited in their number and time. Moderators are exception handlers and the only exceptions now are *good* questions if even that. We need to give powerful tools to more users if we want to make a difference with question quality – and that's what this proposal does.

Comment: @Won't I can understand that. There's a second more subtle issue, too: There is no rationale given. While a problem may seem "obvious" to you, this is a particularly sensitive topic in that generally calls for anything to increase power are met with blind agreement as most people want more power (not necessarily in a greedy or devious way). You should give a clear analysis that shows that the questions are a problem and that the suggested inability to currently handle them well is causing an issue, otherwise it has more of a bandwagony kind of vibe to it, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Won't Incidentally, is this unique to SO or do you see it as an issue on other sites? What about the smaller sites (i.e. not Programmers, SO, SU, etc.)? The discussion keeps gravitating to SO specifically.

Comment: @Won't Could there be both options? *1.) Yes I'm sure and this should be closed immediately* and  *2.) Should go through the review as I might be wrong.*  If not, the side effect could be that some questions won't be touched even if the should go through the review.

Comment: What's really being asked, @Won't , is for you to verify that this is an objectively bad problem that everyone is experiencing. Sure, we see that you are obviously perturbed by it, but what we don't see is that everyone is, and further that this would resolve the problem.  It's not a bad idea in and of itself, but it has no foundation on which all can agree, and thus there's little to base agreement or disagreement on other than individual subjective perceptions. Bringing hard data to the table is difficult, but until someone does, all we can do is wave our hands and choose the bikeshed color.

Comment: Can the commentators please post answers for additional suggestions or new view points? Comments really aren't well fit for extended discussions which extend this long.

Comment: @bummi that's part of the proposal--direct action requires comment, whereas casting your vote without comment acts as a normal close vote that is not binding.

Comment: @AdamDavis I know, I understand, but I also can't, because I don't want to spend the time on something that I feel is obvious on its face to many users. It's up to the voters to disagree if they feel it isn't pressing enough an issue to give this type of power to a larger segment of the user base.

Comment: @Won't Do not mistake those who are requesting a rationale for people who disagree or "just don't get it". For this issue, upvotes will not get the feature implemented (and downvotes will not prevent it). SE is your target, not voting users. The SE team has shown themselves to excel at seeing the bigger picture. There are two main possibilities: SE already is on your side of the fence, in which case the feature eventually is implemented, no rationale necessary. Or: SE is not on your side of the fence, in which case you'll need a strong argument. *However*: Not providing an argument runs the...

Comment: ...risk of *dooming related request for the foreseeable future*, presuming the second case above. It's up to you whether or not you want to risk creating an "Occupy" here and wasting a potentially good opportunity to bring about a change. It's easy to mistake public support as genuine understanding of the issue when really it reflects a successful appeal to desire for power instead. If you're confident and feel strongly that the SE team already mostly agrees then you don't need to say anything more, but there is a far reaching risk. I only speak for myself but my requests are intended to help.

Comment: I like the pseudo-German appearance of _Onholdhammer_. If I'm going to be accused while using it of being a power-mad member of a certain historical paramilitary organization (and I'm [pretty sure I would be](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293854)), I'd at least like to have a suitable title to go along with it, and I don't think _Obersturmbahnfuhrer_ would fly.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Zurückgestelltehammer!  or Haltenhammer!

Comment: Oooh, _Haltenhammer_ is even better!

Comment: @JoshCaswell [obligatory](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8FSbG.png)

Comment: Something that doesn't sit right with me about this is: Reputation is currently used system-wide as a rough approximation of trust. Therefore it is appropriate for this use as well. If reputation fails to be appropriate for determining trust for a given privilege, then reputation is failing its job (and yes, it's already a given that the rep system is a weak but relatively working system to determine "trust"). If reputation is failing its job that's a conversation to be had on its own instead of applying band-aids in specific cases (like using different criteria for this "closehammer").

Comment: (Gold tag badges are involved in the trust approximation system as well, which is debatably a band-aid on its own but not necessarily a justification for adding even more "trust determination workarounds".)

Comment: @JasonC You need to bug the folks who use reputation as a measure of ability to moderate successfully.  Moderation requires understanding the goals and standards of the website, not how to use tail recursion to solve euclid's sudoku or sommet.

Comment: @Won't No, *you* need to bug them. You're the one proposing new ideas and viewing the current system as inadequate here. I'm OK enough with the current system. :P

Comment: @BartoszKP your lack of humor is offensive to me.

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm not removing the picture, and you're free to keep the comment up. It's been only 70 years, I know, but I think it's fine to make a joke-meme at the expense of fascists.

Answer (score 20):

Even senior/trusted users can disagree, so this will need some additional safeguards to avoid close/reopen loops.

On the "what privileges should we give to 30k users?" question I proposed [expedited closures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252698/162102) with the following limitations:

> - Instantly put a question on hold for any reason *other* than duplicate, provided that:
>
>   - The question has not been previously closed and reopened.
>   - The question, if in the review queue, does not have pending "leave open" votes.
>   - (Maybe - open for discussion): the question is on the front page or, failing the ability to implement that, "new" (definition TBD).
> - Instantly reopen a question that was put on hold by a 30k user, provided that:
>
>   - The question has been edited since it was put on hold.

This would exclude duplicates (already covered) and migrations (more disruptive, so should involve a mod or community vote).

That was in the context of high-rep users, but I can see your argument that an *actual track record of good moderation* is a good basis.  We all know high-rep users who rarely vote, flag, or review, and lower-rep users who do a lot here.  I think the following (in some combination) would be reasonable factors:

- Enough reputation to cast close votes.  (I can see this being a 10k privilege, but even if it's not you still need to be able to cast, and have a record of casting, close votes.)
- Has voted to close some minimum number of questions (100?) *and* maintains some level of ongoing activity (some number of close reviews in the last month, for example).
- Has raised helpful flags on at least 50 (?) posts (comments excluded) *and* no more than 10% (?) of resolved flags in the last month were declined.  (More than 10% declined in 7 days is where you [start to get warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/162102); I kept the percentage and lengthened the period so privs wouldn't oscillate as much.)
- Convention badge: meta is important.

The specific criteria can and should be tweaked, but something in that general ballpark is a good baseline for "we trust this user to do this".

I didn't include a measure of "successful" close votes because that's hard.  That a question got reopened doesn't mean it shouldn't have been closed; maybe it needed and got an edit, or there was a scope discussion on meta resulting in a change.  I'd like to capture some measure of "doesn't screw up closures too much", but I don't know what to do there.

Comment: The tone of this comment is neutral. Do you believe there is a "slippery slope" (either in a bad *or* a good way) component to this type of criteria? This would become the only site privilege that isn't based on a simple rep threshold or single badge. It is a significant outlier, and opens the door to a similar discussion wrt other privileges by setting a precedent. I'm *positive* such discussions have taken place before but I can't find them, if I do I'll post links.

Comment: I don't believe badges are a good matrix, out of all the options there are, especially that they aren't retracted.

Comment: @JasonC I see the "slippery slope" argument.  There are a couple privileges that are not rep-based, but they're rare.  The dupe-hammer is tag-based, and standing for election on some sites requires certain badges.  So in a sense we're already on the slope, but I agree we need to be careful.  I originally proposed this as a 30k privilege and think that idea still works, but I also see value in using criteria that are closely related to the privilege in question, if we think we can get it right.

Comment: @Unihedron Deputy is a proxy for "has a minimum number of helpful flags", and goes with a "not too many bad ones" that's needed to keep this from being gamed.  I'd like *some* measure of meta contribution but it doesn't need to be that one; any suggestions?

Comment: How about top 40% in terms of amount of helpful flags - declined flags without taking into account <3k (or Beta equivalent rep for closing) users when sorting by the net flag count of every site?

Comment: @Unihedron comment and post flags, or just the latter?  (I don't really want to create an incentive for people to flag *every single comment* in a thread instead of flagging the post to tell us the whole thread is obsolete.)

Comment: I don't know. Flag weight relative to site, close votes history relative to performance, etc seems more trusty figures than helpful flags that scores a badge (and it's not even that hard, considering I have Marshal on Drupal where I don't participate on, and Deputy on various sites network wide).

Comment: That's a good point.  Some notion of time-based flag weight would give a more accurate picture.  Let me think about how we could do that.

Comment: It's been two days - how's your thought experiment?

Comment: @Unihedron see my edit.  I changed it to a minimum number of flags on *posts only* (no gaming it by searching for "thanks" or "+1" comments) plus a recent track record of helpful flags.  The specific numbers can be tweaked, of course, but I think I'm in the right ballpark.

Comment: To add to the "slippery slope" concerns, it strikes me that this would be the only privilege I'm aware of that a regular user can't tell if someone has from info on that person's profile page. It's not just that it's somewhat complicated, it's that the relevant info is currently only visible to the user themselves (and maybe diamond mods, not sure what you guys see). With other privileges, it's either rep-based or based on *preexisting* badges, while this is not.

Comment: @cpast interesting point.  I hadn't considered that, though I also don't know how much it matters because anybody who *uses* the power leaves a public record (the closures).  Is it important to know who has the privilege?  (Any privilege, for that matter?)  We also don't know who's currently flag-banned or review-banned, to approach it from the other direction, so you don't actually know that someone has a privilege just because he has the indicators.

Comment: My concern remains that these requirements aren't a better matrix over the other options to be used. To run on, point 1 is moot because point 2 directly covers that, while point 2 is moot for the same reason [in my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256661/266094) - that "no __arbitrary__ matrix is capable of measuring effectiveness of their ability to close." Point three covers generous values (relative to SO, anyway) though the `(?)`s kinds of signifies how hard it is to set the marker. Then again if you can't come up with where they are set, I don't believe anyone else could either. ;)

Comment: The "?" is an indication that these numbers could be tweaked.  I think the values I've chosen make sense on all but three of our 130+ sites; the trilogy may need a different value.  But you could say the same of other things that are not currently different on the trilogy sites; maybe people there should need more rep in order to do some things, should get more flags or close votes, etc.  That's a separate matter.  If you set values based on SO you make the feature useless for the vast majority of the sites.  On Mi Yodeya we only have two dupe-hammers, for instance.

Comment: What doesn't sit right with me about this whole thing is this: Reputation is currently used system-wide as a rough approximation of trust. Therefore it is appropriate for this use as well. If reputation fails to be appropriate for determining trust for a given privilege, then reputation is failing its job (and yes, it's already a given that the rep system is a weak but relatively working system to determine "trust"). If reputation is failing its job that's a conversation to be had on its own instead of applying band-aids in specific cases (like using different criteria for this "closehammer").

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "If you set values based on SO you make the feature useless for the vast majority of the sites." That's exactly why this feature __is supposed to be hard to get and scaling for site-user growth__, much like on a beta site where it's difficult to have enough questions for a user to submissively answer and score in to earn a gold badge in the field, not that many questions in the field / tag would exist to require a dupehammer, which of its sole intent is for experts of the tag to sort out the problems that arise from having many questions in the tag.

Comment: To sum off my rant, I describe your values as generous because they are. More users would get this privilege than there needs to be, at that point it would be just as effective to appoint more moderators.

Comment: @JasonC then consider voting on the linked proposal for this as a 30k privilege. :-)  That's where my ideas on this started.

Comment: @Unihedron we will have to agree to disagree, then.  I think we should be trying to design for the network at large, not just for SO, and non-trilogy sites need expedited closure in some cases too.  On some of my sites a bad question can pick up several answers before five people cast close votes, and we should address that.  If you need to raise the calibration on SO then do that, but anything calibrated for SO will fail on 99% of sites, so that's not a good use of development effort.  This is far from the only case of "SO is different", as I've already noted.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I already voted on that last month when you posted it. :)

Comment: @MonicaCellio If a site is too small to have any users with close hammers, doesn't that mean its small enough for the existing close queue and/or moderators to manage? The whole premise (I assume, although I may be being generous) behind close hammers is giving more users more power to make up for the normal system being overwhelmed on larger sites (which, incidentally, probably warrants a discussion of how to fix an allegedly broken close system rather than giving users extra power as a kludge to make up for it). Do you think a "close hammer" is needed on smaller sites?

Comment: @JasonC you'd think, but for example on Workplace, we regularly get questions that need to be put on hold but attract multiple answers before collecting the five votes needed to do that.  This is especially a problem with newly-asked questions from new users; those often need a round of refinement because they come up with discussion-forum posts instead of answerable questions.  I wish our users were better about *not answering* questions that should be closed, but we're still working on that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Maybe a concept of "deputies" could be a different approach. E.g. users with certain mod-like privileges (such as insta close) chosen at will by existing moderators (a human-based "trust metric", if you will). Perhaps with a settable time limit (on the order of weeks), so deputies could be chosen in times of need but the privileges revoked without drama/friction (the system revokes rather than a mod revoking). To be clear: I don't like that idea because I am against increasing unilateral powers in general for various reasons, but just throwing it out there.

Comment: Also, close-hammers are tied to tags, so if a site has a lot of less-densely populated tags rather than fewer bigger ones, you won't see dupe-hammers.  That *doesn't* mean that the sites don't need them yet; it just means the tag hierarchy is differently structured.  (Or, as is frequently the case in my experience, unstructured and just grew that way. :-) )

Comment: I've not read all the comments, there are too many, but I did read your proposal for 30k users to put on hold/close questions single-handedly. **I hope this proposal never goes through**.  I'll explain the obvious pitfall, on EL&U and ELL there was a particular vigilant member (+25k) who went through the archives voting to close questions which s/he argued oid not meet the site's guidelines. Fair enough. if another four users agreed, the question was then closed. [Cont'd]

Comment: [Cont'd] BUT, if s/he had the privilege of closing questions that were older than a week, I guarantee that the number of  questions closed unilaterally on EL&U  would have reached the + hundred mark on a weekly basis. All you need is one zealot user with a high rep, which is not impossible, and you have the recipe for a sea of extermination. This user has since deleted their account, s/he frequently  got suspended, but the suspensions never affected their rep.

Comment: A **trusted user**, should not be based on their rep alone, it should also take into account whether that user has been suspended for longer than a week i.e. the cooling off period, in their user history.

Answer (score 6):

I like this idea.

However, there are problems with the suggestion.

**Making closing incredibly easy for a sector of users** means that they are treated as **stewards** for closing.

(In case you didn't know, stewards are those with a heavy responsibility to look after someone's property.)

As a result, they tend to **close more than to downvote** like anyone else could do. *Especially in the case of Stack Overflow*, each close voter gets **50** close votes a day, but only **40** up/down votes. Try to convince anyone how they will still vote fairly and not overuse their ability where they should be downvoting instead.

Additionally, **no arbitrary matrix** is capable of **measuring effectiveness of their ability to close**. Unlike providing the Close Votes Review queue, users don't pass through "are you still sane?" checks in form of audits. **It is incredibly difficult to correct mistakes if they don't get noticed soon enough.**

As my last point, **closing is for questions with serious problems** that are not likely to be improved into answerable state whatsoever. Implementing this feature means sites like Stack Overflow will become a battleground where trusted users battle low quality questions. This is not healthy, for all of these parties:

- Audience (guests who look for answers)
- Askers (They might get shot down any moment)
- Answerers (Accused for not helping to shoot down more questions; Have a narrower source of reputation points)
- Moderation parties, caretakers (labelled into "stewards" and "non-stewards", divert in moderation decisions causes hammer misuse and frequent problems)
- The pathetic people shaking their heads (seeing the site officially become battlegrounds isn't fun)

Comment: All good points of concern.  However, I'd argue one point--that StackOverflow is *already such a battleground*, but one where opposing forces of good and crap are more evenly matched than I think they should be.

Comment: "closing is for questions with serious problems that are not likely to be improved into answerable state whatsoever" No. That's the criteria for deletion. Closing is a marker that the question either is off-topic or doesn't meet quality standards and can easily be reversed provided OP puts in the effort to improve the question. With closevotes, you should vote early and often, there is no need for wait or making sure it's unsalvageable.

Comment: @Won't I'd like statistics or realistic entries showing exactly how Stack Overflow is such a battleground that it won't get worse after implementing this or how this feature would mitigate / reduce / solve the problem you mentioned.

Comment: ^ I strongly concur with the above comment, I would also like to see that analysis. I'm not passionately for or against this idea, I just think it would make for a much stronger case, and would also be really interesting. Right now it seems to just appeal too much to a reasonable general desire for more power without a concrete rationale.

Comment: @bjb568: While I wholeheartedly agree with you as one who votes to close with your exact same criteria, the help center states differently. I quote: "[...]. If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked [on hold], it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be considered for reopening. If it is not reopened within five days, the [on hold] notice automatically changes to [closed].There is functionally no difference between an [on hold] question and a [closed] one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but they both allow comments, votes and edits."

Comment: @bjb568: [continued] Closed questions are quickly split into "Improved" and "Idle" groups. If a post isn't improved in time (5 days), they will not go back into the reopen queue again (and given the attention they get as a closed question, they seldom do). Even if a post is improved, they have to be "approved" for reopening by community users, each with their own judgement. Under this closing system, the "on hold" mark is no longer only a marker for temporal problems, but instead a seal for a high potential for the question to be banished. Forever.

Comment: Makes sense given that OP almost never improves the question and it's impossible for other community members to salvage it. These questions should die without OP intervention.

Comment: I appreciate your judgement but don't think that rationale is what makes this feature worthwhile.

Comment: I'd definitely agree with having to have a way of tracking the impact and effectiveness of this change prior to implementation. It's a big stretch, no doubt.  If the impact is negative, it should be known.

Comment: You can prevent battles (via this privilege, anyway) by limiting which questions can be closed in this way, as I laid out in my answer.  Don't enable further oscillation; that's no good for anybody.  A close-hammer should apply *once* per question, not every time a privileged user comes along and disagrees with the state of the question.

Comment: @Monica: That doesn't prevent any battles at all, only mistakes in the highly visited spectrum. "sites like Stack Overflow will become a battleground where trusted users battle low quality questions" <- Your answer mitigates none of this problem that arises from this "feature", neither resolves any of the problems I listed here.

Comment: You seem to be talking about the "close! no, open! no close!" tugs of war that currently require five users on each site (and no repeats IIRC; you only get to VtC once).  I'm saying that by limiting which questions a unilateral close (or reopen) can apply to you mitigate *that* type of tug of war.  The broader one is beyond the scope of this feature request; we just want to avoid making it worse.  You seem to be saying "can't make it perfect so don't bother making it better"; I disagree with that.  But we both have answers, so we should make our cases there, not in comments back and forth.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "You seem to be talking about the 'close! no, open! no close!' tugs of war that currently require five users on each site (and no repeats IIRC; you only get to VtC once)." No. I'm talking about how Stack Overflow caretakers takes the front page as a waterfall of zombies from Plants vs Zombies.

Comment: I rather think that narrowing the source for rep points for the dupe-answering FGITW [retired term] is one of the goals here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I like this idea. I *may* like this idea if a more concrete rationale with evidence is given. However, I dislike the idea of giving more users  unilateral powers, as I am personally a big fan of community handling of tasks. I also am not sure if old low-view poor content is necessarily a problem to be urgently solved -- if nobody really views it then it's not *really* watering down information quality on the site (which is the fundamental problem being identified here).

That said, the dupe-hammer seems to be working well; but that does not cause (or lead to, by opening up the possibility of delete) loss of content.

In any case, presuming that a) the community truly can't handle bad content effectively and b) said bad content is problematic and has a negative impact on the site's quality, I would rather see other ideas for calling attention to such content besides giving more unilateral super powers all around.

The surface problem being identified here is that old content sticks around a long time and not enough people notice it to deal with.

In the current system if somebody *does* notice the content and CVs it, it will go to the close review queue, with the hopes that ultimately others see it. The OP's proposal does not show that the current close review queue system is inadequate, but let's assume that it is for the sake of discussion.

To that end I think a better solution to the underlying problem would be to **prioritize questions with close votes cast by gold badge holders in the close review queue**. This is a balance. No new unilateral powers are given, but trusted users essentially gain the ability to call the community to more quickly look at specific questions that they deem are bad. There is no real possibility for abuse here. Does this negatively impact the review queue as far as questions with no gold badge votes on them? I don't know. I don't have the ability to perform that kind of analysis.

Another possible way to address the *more fundamental issue of information quality* could be to auto flag old low scoring questions that exceed a certain views per time threshold. This draws attention to old, potentially bad questions that *may actually be having an impact on the world due to views*. What should these thresholds be? I don't know.

But mostly, gold badge close review queue priority is my choice here as a balance. I realize it may not satisfy many people's reasonable desire for more power but I am not necessarily sure that that is a bad thing. Also the success of it could potentially be a foundation for implementing a "close hammer" in the future, or at the very least may provide some interesting data to back up such a proposal.

Comment: "... could be to auto flag old low scoring questions that exceed a certain views per time threshold." With the test runs of the Triage queue on Stack Overflow, I think you got it.

Comment: If you don't like unilaterality of closing for non-mods, how about increasing the weight of some CVs, possibly only requiring 2 or 3 to close some questions?

Comment: @bjb568 I could stand by that as well. I feel like I've seen that suggested before. I was actually looking for it earlier but couldn't find it.

Comment: @bjb568 But I wonder if it would have the desired effect. If it's not drawing any more attention to the question than the current system, does it help? We'd want to gather some data on how many CVs old unclosed questions actually get before the votes decay (assuming that happens) to see if it would be effective. Most of the thoughts in my answer revolved specifically around drawing attention to unnoticed content, but maybe that is a good different approach.

Comment: Sounds like what I proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver) except I was answering a question about what to give to silver badge holders.

Comment: Having a tag badge makes you better able to judge if something is a dupe, but it seems completely orthogonal to evaluating whether a question is unclear, opinion-based, etc.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Having a tag badge doesn't make you better able to judge anything. Having a tag badge is currently used as a rough approximation of trust. The dupehammer is given based on that trust. Close vote queue priority could be given based on that trust as well. Gold tag badges aren't a measure of your ability to do anything, they're a rough trust metric, a simplified, already-existing approximation (at least that's their intent) of the set of criteria [you proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256669/230261). In the end, gold badges and more complex criteria are equally inaccurate.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't mind using gold badges to indicate that a specific user is trusted to perform more than the usual moderation tasks on a specific sub-area of a site, fwiw. But a plain old reputation threshold with site-wide privileges works just as well as all the other suggestions here, too.

Comment: *Only* allowing this for gold badge-holders wouldn't help most sites, but if you're saying do that in *addition* to something broader, that works.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Reputation would be the appropriate choice then. If improvements to the reputation system are required before it is appropriate for closehammers, then the world is not ready for closehammers yet and reputation system improvements should be discussed first. That said, if smaller sites are lacking gold badges this probably means that they just don't *need* the users with extra privileges due to their small manageable size. So I actually don't see much issue with that; it seems to be acceptable re: lack of dupe hammers at least.

Comment: I like the auto-flag idea.  We have auto-flags for many comments and many answers, so many views in a short time window fits into that pattern.  It'd be nice to find a way to make that information available to more than just the moderators, though; while only mods can clean up long comment threads, lots of people can take appropriate actions on suddenly-popular questions that might have issues.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of giving trusted users nuclear weapons, why not give them bigger guns? Instead of being able to unilaterally close a question, just have their close vote count as 2 or 3 or 4 votes. Then you still get some community oversight.