# Association bonus conflicts with 'Trusted User' privilege

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges, association-bonus, trusted-user

When you hit 200 reputation on any Stack Exchange site, you are met with the  prompt:

> You've earned a bonus 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network.

The key part is:  **because we trust you.**

The recipient thinks:  "Yay!  I'm a trusted member of this site!".  Right?

**Wrong.** 

[Apparently](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you don't become 'trusted' until you reach 20k rep.  Twenty-thousand. That's a **lot** (emphasis on lot) of reputation just to call someone 'trusted'.

This is my complaint/request.  I have always questioned the usage of this wording at such a high bar.

Reasons:

- That's super high just to give someone the liberty to feel 'trusted' on this site.  Then what where they before?  **Not** trusted?
- You already said they're trusted 19.8k rep ago, when they got the assoc.

Request:

**Change the 20k privilege wording to something like:**

- Notable user
- High-profile user
- Pronounced user

**OR:**

Change the 200 rep privilege to something like:

- Growing user
- Advancing user
- Rising newcomer

Even [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256657/lets-give-very-trusted-users-a-closehammer-to-go-with-their-dupehammer) opts into putting 'very' in the title.

Comment: 200 rep: you are trusted not to be a spammer and to know the basics of Stack Exchange, 20k rep: You are trusted by the site community to be a expert member with additional privileges (quick question deletion, answer deletion, ...)

Comment: You say it's "confusing to many," but this is the first complaint I've heard at least.

Comment: @Lordology: I've noticed that your questions lately all seem to have a common theme: nitpicking over word usage. I'm curious as to why exactly these seemingly trivial issues matter so much? Yes, these two things both use the word "trust", but why is it so unreasonable for it to be said in a stronger sense elsewhere? There are a lot of things that people frequently misunderstand about SE, but the difference between "we trust you" and "you're a trusted user" isn't one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is:

> You've earned a bonus 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network.

Nowhere in there does it say that you're a Trusted User. It just says you're trusted. As @MEE mentioned, "because we trust you on other sites in the network" means that you're trusted enough to not be a spammer and get past the basic new user restrictions. While it *could* be confused with the Trusted User privilege, it seems to me to be a fairly large distinction between "You earned the Trusted User privilege" and "We trust you on other sites in the network".

Answer (score 6):

The key here is that there is no privilege for the 200 rep, it's just a bonus. The "because we trust you" is just part of a friendly inbox message **that does not appear anywhere else**.

The user see it once, smiles, and moves on.

On the other hand, the "Trusted User" privilege has its own page, it's part of any site privileges list, and comes after "Established User" privilege.

So personally I don't see any reason to change either of those. Let the association bonus message stay friendly and clear, and the actual privilege to keep its name as it exists for over 10 years by now.